# UIWebView interaction hide uitoolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uibutton, uitoolbar

When you touch/scroll/pinch/etc. (ie interact) with a `UIWebView`, I want to hide a `UIToolbar` element to imitate a "Full Screen" look and bring the toolbar back with a `UIButton` click. Any way to determine when the UIWebView is touched?

Thanks! Any sample code is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this sample worked for me before:

https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/tree/master/WebViewTappingHack

Answer (score 0):

I think for doing something like that you'd have to subclass UIWebView and implement some of the UIView methods for tap event handling. Then use a delegate to let other objects know what to do. You could even set timeouts and such to automate it.